# if a billinear transformation $ \ f \ $ sends real axis to the imaginary axis

Tags: complex-analysis

Show that if a billinear transformation $ \ f \ $ sends real axis to the imaginary axis and the point $ \ 1 \ \ to \ \ \infty \ $ , then  $ \ f \ $ sends every circle passing through $ 1 \ $ with centre $ (a,0) , \ \ a \in \mathbb{R} \ $ to a line parallel to the real axis.

**Answer:**

The map $ f(z)=w=\frac{i z}{z-1} \ $ sends the real axis to the imaginary axis and the point $ \ 1 \ \ to \ \ \infty \ $ .

Now any circle passing through $ 1 \ $ is $ \ |z-1|=r , \ \ r \in \mathbb{R} \ $ .

i.e., $ z=1+re^{i \theta} \ $ .

But If I put $ z=1+re^{i \theta} \ $  in  $ f(z)=w=\frac{i z}{z-1} \ $  , **how can I show that it will be a line parrallel to the real axis ?**

**Is there any help ?**

Comment: You can't just assume that $f(z)=\frac{iz}{z-1}$...

Comment: so how to do ? any help ?

Comment: Note that $|z-1|=r$ represents a circle *with center* $1$, not a circle passing through $1$.

Answer (score 2):

You use the properties of bilinear mappings.

First off all the images of circles through $1$ will include $\infty$. And since they map circlines to circlines and a circline through $\infty$ is a line their images are lines.

Second you use that they are conform so since the preimage intersects the real axis at right angle then the image must intersect the image of the real axis (that is the imaginary axis) at right angle.

---

Note that an expression for the mapping is also possibly, but requires more calculating. The general expression for such a map is.

$$z \mapsto {i(pz + q)\over(z-1)}$$

Where $p,q\in\mathbb R$. The mapping is not uniquely determined by the requirements. However we see that the nominator is just a scaling and translation (except for the $i$ which is a rotation). So you just need to investigate the mapping

$$z\mapsto {i\over z-1}$$

If we rewrite the equation of the circle in parametric form we get $z = a + (a-1)e^{i\theta}$ and the denominator becomes $a-1 + (a-1)e^{i\theta} = (a-i)(1+e^{i\theta})$. Then it's just some calculation of the image:

$${i\over (a-1)(1+e^{i\theta})} = {i\over a-1}{1+e^{-i\theta}\over (1+e^{i\theta})(1+e^{-i\theta})} \\
= {i\over a-1}{1 + \cos \theta + i\sin \theta\over 2(1+\cos\theta)}\\
= {i\over a-1}\left({1\over 2}+i{\sin \theta \over1+\cos\theta}\right)$$

Only left to see is that the range of $\sin\theta/(1+\cos\theta)$ makes this a line parallell to the real axis.